# is there any UML editor library for web application?

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, uml

Just want to know is there any library or frameworks support for the UML editor interface to the web application.
I know they are many online tools available for creating UML diagrams. But need to know is there any option available for integrate the UML creator interface into the web application.

Answer (score 2):

I like very much MermaidJS (http://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/)

I use that on my own blog for diagrams.

Here is an example for flowchart (https://www.guilhermevrs.me/posts/time-management-for-leaders/)

Here is the code:

```
graph TD;
begin(Start)
id1{Is it an action for you?};
id2[Store as reference]
id3[Delegate]
id4[Delete]
id5{Less than 2 minutes?}
id6[Do it!]
id7["Categorize it #40;e.g. work, personal, etc#41;"]
id8["Prioritized it #40;e.g. priority 1, priority 2, etc#41;"]
id9["Size it #40;e.g. XS, S, M, etc#41;"]
id10{Due date?}
id11[Schedule it]
id12{Should follow-up?}
id13[Schedule reminder]
id14(Done)
begin-->id1
id1-- No, but may be useful -->id2
id1-- No, it's not up to me -->id3
id1-- No, it's irrelevant now -->id4
id1-- Yes -->id5
id5-- Yes -->id6
id5-- No -->id10
id10-- No -->id7
id10-- Yes -->id11
id11-->id7
id7-->id8
id8-->id9
id3-->id12
id12-- No --> id14
id12-- Yes -->id13
id13 & id9 & id6 & id4 & id2-->id14
```

Comment: Thank You. @Guihermevrs but looks like there is no option for creating shape from an editor like drag and drop?

Comment: @GowriShankar No, there is no drag and drop editor.  MermaidJS uses a Markdown like syntax to allow quick declaration of diagrams, that will then be rendered as such.  My first exposure to mermaid was with GitLab, which uses it inline with markdown files to display in their website